# Mazimisation problem with Lagrange's mutipliers

Tags: optimization, radicals, lagrange-multiplier, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> $ Let f(x,y,z) = 4x^{1/4}y^{1/4}z^{1/4} $
>
> Given that f is concave , maximize f(x,y,z) over R^{3} subject to $
>  x+y = 3$ and $ y+z = 3 $

$L(x,y,z  ,  \lambda) =  4x^{1/4}y^{1/4}z^{1/4} + \lambda_{1}(3-x-y) + \lambda_{2}(3-y-z) $

end up with 5 equations in 5 unknowns, however I am so lost as to how to solve this, 
$ \Delta_{x}L=$

$ x^{-3/4}y^{1/4}z^{1/4} - \lambda_{1} = 0$

,$  x^{1/4}y^{-3/4}z^{1/4} - \lambda_{1} - \lambda_{2} = 0 $

$   x^{-1/4}y^{1/4}z^{-3/4} - \lambda_{2}   = 0   $

$ x +y = 3$

$y+z=3$

from the last two equations I get x = z , so I  can eliminate z, however this only gives me

$ x^{-1/2}y^{1/4} = \lambda_{1}$

$x^{1/2}y^{-3/4} -\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2} =0   $

$  x^{-1/2}y^{1/4} = \lambda_{2}   $

I just cant solve this from here, keep going round in circles trying to eliminate variables

Comment: It seems from the last that $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$

Comment: Yes I get this aswell, however it doesn't help to solve the problem cause I am left with x y and $\lambda_{1}$

Comment: Doesn't it imply that $x^{1/2}y^{-3/4} $=0?

Comment: How is $f$ defined if $x,y$ or $z$ are negative?

Comment: Why does it imply that  $x^ 1/2 y^{ −3/4}  
x^1/2y^{−3/4}
=0$  I don't see how that equals 0

Answer (score 3):

By AM-GM
$$4\sqrt[4]{xyz}=4\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{2}x\cdot2y\cdot z}\leq4\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x+2y+z}{3}\right)^3}=4\sqrt2.$$
The equality occurs for $x+y=y+z=3$ and $x=2y=z$, id est, for $(x,y,z)=(2,1,2)$,
which gives that $4\sqrt2$ is a maximal value.

Answer (score 1):

> $ x^{-1/2}y^{1/4} = \lambda_{1}$
>
> $x^{1/2}y^{-3/4} -\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{2} =0   $
>
> $  x^{-1/2}y^{1/4} = \lambda_{2}   $

Plug the first and last into the middle one:
$$x^{1/2}y^{-3/4} -x^{-1/2}y^{1/4}-x^{-1/2}y^{1/4} =0$$
For $xy \ne 0$, multiply by $x^{1/2}y^{3/4}$ to get:
$$x-y-y =0 \iff x = 2y$$
Now check the different cases and remember that $x=z$:

- $x=0=z$, then by $x+y=3 \implies y = \ldots$
- $y=0$, then by $x+y=3 \implies x = \ldots = z$
- $x=2y$, then...

Answer (score 1):

substitution from equations 1 and 3 in 2 concludes that $x=z=2$ and $y=1$